# unable to initailize multiple lightslider instances

Tags: jquery

I would like to have multiple instances of lightslider [lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html)

but only seem to be able to initialize one instance, the 2nd instance doesn't work correctly. I found a jquery each loop on the lightslider github that I have implemented but can't quite get it to work.

slider.html

```
 <div class="slider-item">
                <ul id="adaptive" class="content-slider">
                    <li>
                        <h3>1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>2</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>3</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>4</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>5</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>6</h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="slider-item">
                <ul id="adaptive" class="content-slider">
                    <li>
                        <h3>1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>2</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>3</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>4</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>5</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>6</h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<script>
function activateSliders(){

$('.adaptive').each(function(){

   var sliderId =  $(this).attr('id');

   $("#" + sliderId).lightSlider({
    adaptiveHeight:false,
    item:1,
    slideMargin:0,
    loop:true,
    pager:false
   });

});
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1) u have duplicated id on 2 lists, id must be unique, getting by id return first existing element...and before each function you select "adaptive" as class.

Comment: yes I appreciate that, but it needs the id to be 'adaptive' to run and looking through the jquery does it not add an id to `id="adaptive"` e.g `id="adaptive 1"` so it would now be unique

Comment: one element can have only one id
1) bad selector before each function
2)create unique id's
i try create good layout because i don't know english well

Comment: watch code above, i update my solution, but if id is unnecessary, replace `selector` to `e`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but I don't understand why you need `id`s.

```js
$('.content-slider').each(function(i, e){
  var id = 'adaptive';
  $(e).attr('id', id+i);
  var selector = '#'+id+i;
   $(selector).lightSlider({
    adaptiveHeight:false,
    item:1,
    slideMargin:0,
    loop:true,
    pager:false
   });
});
```

```css
.content-slider{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider-item{margin-top: 50px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>

 <div class="slider-item">
                <ul class="content-slider">
                    <li>
                        <h3>1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>2</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>3</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>4</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>5</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>6</h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="slider-item">
                <ul class="content-slider">
                    <li>
                        <h3>1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>2</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>3</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>4</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>5</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>6</h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, if i move `"adaptive" to class it doesn't work, think I'll try a different plugin, can't get this working

Comment: how it don't work, run my code snippet...i create for u live demo with 2 working sliders...

Comment: if you don't understand why didn't work, just trust me, remove id and add class `adaptive` to both ul tags, than replace your code to `$('.adaptive').each(function(i, e){
   $(e).lightSlider({`

Comment: Brilliant thank you! It works using your code I'll use this for now. I don't think it loaded properly so didn't see it working previously

Comment: What is the `up vote 0 down vote favorite` in this answer? Why does the question seem to have been pasted in here?